# Why is my vnc hosted ubuntu machine doesn't have wifi or network settings?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, vnc, wsl2

I have a vnc hosted ubuntu machine that is running on localhost, when I go to settings the network section doesn't have the ethernet settings or the wireless setting can anyone help me?

here is the image of the settings

[image]

Comment: Did the administrator of the VM add a network interface? If they did, check dmesg to see why the network interface isn't properly initialized.

Comment: What should i look for the dmesg? @mtak